# Como aplicar typescript en el lado del cliente sin que de error por uso de require

Tags: nodejs, typescript, express

Intento adaptar un proyecto con `Node`, `Express` y `Mongo` a `typescript` y me gusta lo que ofrece. Todo funciona perfecto en el lado del servidor. Pero al aplicarlo en el lado del cliente me indica error porque el archivo .js transpilado me importa los módulos con `require`, y este no lo soporta el navegador por defecto.
He encontrado soluciones como la de usar `RequireJS` pero... pienso que debe de haber alguna solución más sencilla, y si no es así, me lo podéis confirmar.

El archivo de configuración `tsconfig.json` para typescript es el siguiente:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2015",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },

    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "files": ["my-types.d.ts"]
}
```

En el archivo .ts importo los módulos de la siguiente manera:

```js
import 'multer';
import 'passport';
import 'connect-flash';
import 'mongoose';
import 'fs-extra';
import 'express';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
```

Y pese a hacerlo así, el archivo .js resultante es el siguiente:

```js
require("multer");
require("passport");
require("connect-flash");
require("mongoose");
require("fs-extra");
require("express");
```